# How to get hostname from an endpoint in SvelteKit?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I want to aggregate JSON data from an endpoint (GET), so I make multiple fetch inside the endpoint. Here's the endpoint :

```
export async function get({ params }) {
    
    let sortedByDate = loadStays().sort((a, b) => { return b.datedebpassage - a.datedebpassage });

    await Promise.all(sortedByDate.map(async (stay) => {
        const res = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/visits/" + stay.visitId);
        if (res.ok) {
            stay.visits = await res.json();
        } else {
            stay.visits = [];
        }
    }));
    return {
        body: sortedByDate,
    };
}
```

The problem is about the url `http://localhost:3000` : How can I use the same hostname as the main endpoint ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The current host is available as `url.host` where `url` s one of the other arguments to the get function

```js
export async function get({ url, params }) {

}
```

> As with all technology, things change over time. The answer below *was* correct at some time, but since the time I posted it originally SvelteKit's API has changed.
>
> Whenever you use StackOverflow, bear in mind the *date* an answer was posted and use your own judgement to see if it is still correct, maybe leave a message to the post, or write your answer.

**for older versions**

The current host is available as `page.host`, where page is one of the other arguments to the load function:

```js
export async function get({ page, params }) {

}
```

alternatively, you could simply leave the host part out of your fetch

```
fetch('/api/...')
```